# "in a way that somebody agrees is of a good enough standard or allowed" — Why is it grammatical to place “agrees” and “is” next to each other?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

one of the meanings of "acceptably" from [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/acceptably):
**(1)** *​acceptably - in a way that somebody agrees is of a good enough standard or allowed*

The two consecutive verbs "agrees" and "is" are confusing me.

Does (1) mean?:
**(2)** *​acceptably - in a way that somebody agrees and that is of a good enough standard or allowed*
If it does, then why is there not a comma between "agrees" and "is" in (1)?
If not, then why is it grammatically correct to place the verbs “agrees” and “is” next to each other?

Comment: Your #2 *in a way that somebody **agrees** and that is of a good enough standard or allowed* isn't valid. If we remove ***and*** and the syntactically optional clause that follows it, we're just left with *in a way that somebody agrees.* But that verb ***agrees*** needs to be followed by something specifying *what* someone agrees (is true). You're trying to separate *Speak in a way that I agree is sensible* into two separate assertions #1 *Speak in a way that I agree with* and #2 *Speak in a way that I think is  sensible*. But you can't really unravel a construction like that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If we insert "_with_" in (2), will it become grammatical: "_in a way that somebody agrees **with** and that is of a good enough standard or allowed_" ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes - including ***with*** would make it syntactically valid. But that gives us a more complex "two-part" assertion that doesn't mean exactly the same as the (perfectly good) original. After all, it's perfectly possible for someone to agree that what I'm saying ***is of a good enough standard*** and/or ***is allowed*** even if they don't actually agree ***with*** what I'm saying. As famously epitomised in [I Disapprove of What You Say, But I Will Defend to the Death Your Right to Say It](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/06/01/defend-say/). Whatever - you can't *improve* the original here.

Comment: *Alice and Bob are doing something [that] Charlie **agrees is** worthwhile.*

Answer (score 2):

**agrees** can be complemented by a finite clause.

> He agrees *the offer was high enough*.

**a manner** (or **a way**) can be defined by a relative clause:

> in a manner | way that ....

and when **agrees** is the verb in the relative clause defining **manner**

> in a manner that someone agrees...

the subject of the finite clause complementing **agrees** appears tacitly in the subject slot of the relative clause:

> in a manner that someone agrees  <sup>a manner</sup> is good enough...

So you end up with "agrees is" but note that there is a syntactic break (pause) between the two verbs.

Comment: In other words, it’s comparable to “She dresses in a way she **thinks looks** good.” This is essentially equivalent in meaning to “She thinks the way she **dresses looks** good” and “She thinks she dresses in a way that looks good.”

Comment: *He agrees the offer was high enough* is a whole sentence, but it can be "inverted" to give the noun phrase *the offer [that] he agrees was high enough.* That's syntactically similar to OP's example, which also isn't a sentence - *in a way that somebody agrees is of a good enough standard or allowed* is just an adverbial phrase.